# Is a more specific question a duplicate if the answers to the earlier question also answer the later question?

Tags: discussion

Specifically:

The top-rated answer to [how to remove trailing whitespace](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/454/whats-the-simplest-way-to-strip-trailing-whitespace-from-all-lines-in-a-file/) also includes the answer to the more specific [how to remove trailing whitespace *on save*](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11421/removing-redundant-whitespaces-on-save-write).

Should the latter be marked as a duplicate?

One potential problem is that if the *answer* were edited or deleted, then it would not longer make sense for the two questions to be marked as duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

The [help center article on duplication](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates) reads:

> The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place. This does not mean that every duplicate will immediately be closed; [we love (some) dupes](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/). There are many ways to ask the same question, and a user might not be able to find the answer if they're asking it a different way.

And [the blog post linked to from there](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/):

> One thing I want to be clear about, though, is that **duplication is not necessarily bad**. Quite the contrary -- some duplication is desirable. There’s often benefit to having multiple subtle variants of a question around, as people tend to ask and search using completely different words, and the better our coverage, the better odds people can find the answer they’re looking for. And isn't that, really, the whole point of this exercise?
>
> Furthermore, **it's OK for duplicate questions to have duplicate answers**.
>
> (...) bear in mind that cultivating and supporting a moderate amount of natural duplication actively helps the community.

In this particular case, since the latter question is a subset of the former, and the former only answers it incidentally, I see no need to mark them as duplicates.